# What is difference between write_lock and read_lock in concurency control? How to implement read_lock in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, concurrency, readwritelock

What is difference between write_lock and read_lock in concurency?
What is allowed in write_lock? What is allowed in read_lock?
In PostgreSQL, write_lock can be implemented with FOR UPDATE

```
SELECT salary 
FROM staff 
WHERE worker_id=1 
FOR UPDATE
```

How to implement read_lock in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT salary 
FROM staff 
WHERE worker_id=1 
FOR SHARE;
```

There are 4 modes possible here. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)

```
UPDATE
NO KEY UPDATE
SHARE
KEY SHARE
```

All the details in the manual.